# Как заставить circle двигаться по path с определенного места?

Tags: css3, html5, svg, svg-animation, smil

Как заставить красный шарик `#circle` следовать по окружности, начиная с позиции `#mainCircle` по нажатию?

```
<svg class="skillSvg" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                                <path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M16.5,215a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 397,0a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 -397,0"/>
                            </g>
                            <g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
                                <circle id="mainCircle" cx="371.408" cy="110.368" r="45" fill="#9CBEFF"/>
                            </g>
                            <circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="tomato" />                               
                                                            
                            <animateMotion from="371.408, 110.368" to="0, 0" href="#circle" dur="5s" begin="mainCircle.click" fill="freeze">
                                <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                            </animateMotion>

                            <!-- Style path -->                                
                            <defs>
                                <filter id="filter0_d" x="11" y="15" width="408" height="408" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>

                                <filter id="filter1_d" x="322.408" y="65.3682" width="98" height="98" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>
                            </defs>
                            <!-- ********** -->
                        </svg>
```

P.s.: делаю сначала скрытым, тк по дефолту #circle в точке 0,0 (угол документа), при нажатии на #mainCircle он появляется и движется, но не с того места.
Для появления по нажатию использую js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mainCircle').click(function() {
            var circle = $('.skillSvg').find('.circleSvg').first();
            circle.show();
            circle.removeClass('circleSvg');
        })
    })
</script>
```

И строчку css:

```
.circleSvg {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант с Path у которого начальная точка находится в центре синего круга

В векторном редакторе рисуем новый path. Первая узловая точка наносится внутри синего круга и поэтому начало движения красного шарика начнется и закончится именно из этой точки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее заменяем в программе path на новый

*Анимация после клика по синей окружности*

```html
<svg class="skillSvg" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                                <path id="motionPath"  fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M 381.35827,107.26268 365.8978,86.648722 348.50477,67.96732 324.66988,49.285919 300.83498,36.402193 273.77916,24.806841 246.72334,18.364978 216.44658,15.788233 184.23727,19.009164 149.45121,27.383586 123.03958,38.978938 96.627939,55.727781 77.946538,71.832438 61.197695,89.225467 47.669783,107.90687 34.786058,130.45339 25.767451,153.64409 18.037215,185.85341 16.5,215 l 2.181402,26.89761 6.441862,30.92094 9.018608,25.12327 12.883725,22.54652 14.172098,19.32558 15.46047,17.39303 15.460471,14.81629 19.969774,11.59535 25.12326,14.81628 22.54652,7.08605 25.76745,6.44186 27.70001,1.93256 29.63257,-1.93256 26.41164,-5.79767 27.70001,-10.30698 23.83489,-12.88373 22.54652,-17.39303 21.90233,-20.61396 18.6814,-27.05582 14.81629,-27.05582 9.66279,-29.63257 5.15349,-34.14187 -1.28837,-32.8535 -5.15349,-32.20932 -11.59535,-29.63256 z">
                             </path>
                            </g>
                            <g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
                                <circle id="mainCircle" cx="371.408" cy="110.368" r="45" fill="#9CBEFF"/>
                            </g>
                            <circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" opacity="0" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="tomato" >                               
                            <!-- До начала анимации красный шарик скрыт-->                              
                              <animate
                                attributeName="opacity" begin="mainCircle.click"
                                dur="0.01s"
                                to="1"
                                fill="freeze" />                             
                            <!--  анимация от синего круга из начальной точки патча M 381.35827,107.26268  -->
                            
                            <animateMotion
                              id="an1"
                              dur="2.5s"
                              begin="mainCircle.click"
                              fill="freeze"
                              keyPoints="0;1"
                              keyTimes="0;1">
                                <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                           
                            </circle>

                            <!-- Style path -->                                
                            <defs>
                                <filter id="filter0_d" x="11" y="15" width="418" height="418" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>

                                <filter id="filter1_d" x="322.408" y="65.3682" width="98" height="98" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>
                            </defs>
                            <!-- ********** -->
                        </svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

При анимации `animateMotion` элемент (красный шарик) будет двигаться из начальной точки патча **M16.5,215** и вернется в ту же точку, сделав полный круг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg class="skillSvg" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                                <path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M16.5,215a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 397,0a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 -397,0"/>
                            </g>
                            <g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
                                <circle id="mainCircle" cx="371.408" cy="110.368" r="45" fill="#9CBEFF"/>
                            </g>
                            <circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="tomato" />                               
                                                            
                            <animateMotion from="371.408, 110.368" to="0, 0" href="#circle" dur="5s" begin="mainCircle.click" fill="freeze">
                                <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                            </animateMotion>

                            <!-- Style path -->                                
                            <defs>
                                <filter id="filter0_d" x="11" y="15" width="408" height="408" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>

                                <filter id="filter1_d" x="322.408" y="65.3682" width="98" height="98" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>
                            </defs>
                            <!-- ********** -->
                        </svg>
```

1. Один из способов изменить точку старта - перерисовать патч, сделав начальной точкой патча (M) ту, которая необходима. (смотрите ответ 2)
2. Использовать пару аргументов `keyPoints` `keyTimes`, которые позволяют перенести точку старта

```
<animateMotion
   id="an1"
   dur="2.5s"
   begin="mainCircle.click"
   fill="freeze"
   keyPoints="0.6;1"
   keyTimes="0;1">
```

```html
<div>
    <button  onclick="an1.beginElement()">forward </button>
</div>  
<svg class="skillSvg" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                                <path id="motionPath"  fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M16.5,215a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 397,0a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 -397,0">
                             </path>
                            </g>
                            <g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
                                <circle id="mainCircle" cx="371.408" cy="110.368" r="45" fill="#9CBEFF"/>
                            </g>
                            <circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" opacity="0" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="tomato" >                               
                            <!-- До начала анимации красный шарик скрыт-->                              
                              <animate
                                attributeName="opacity" begin="an1.begin"
                                dur="0.01s"
                                to="1"
                                fill="freeze" />                                 
                            <!-- Первая половина анимации от синего круга до начальной точки патча M16.5,215  -->
                            
                        <animateMotion
                               id="an1"
                               dur="2s"
                               begin="indefinite"
                               repeatCount="1"
                               keyPoints="0.6;1"
                               keyTimes="0;1"
                               calcMode="linear"
                               fill="freeze" >
                             <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                        </animateMotion> 
                                            
                            </circle>

                            <!-- Style path -->                                
                            <defs>
                                <filter id="filter0_d" x="11" y="15" width="418" height="418" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>

                                <filter id="filter1_d" x="322.408" y="65.3682" width="98" height="98" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>
                            </defs>
                            <!-- ********** -->
                        </svg>
```

Как видно, что начальную точку старта сдвинули назад  `keyPoints="0.6;1"` к синему кругу, но красный шарик закончил свою анимацию в той точке откуда должен был начать движение без сдвига.

3. Чтобы заставить шарик делать полный круг от синей окружности до синей, необходимо добавить вторую анимацию

```
 <animateMotion
     id="an2"
     dur="5s"
     begin="an1.end"
     fill="freeze"
     keyPoints="0;0.6"
     keyTimes="0;1">
     <mpath href="#motionPath" />
     </animateMotion>
```

```html
<div>
    <button  onclick="an1.beginElement()">forward </button>
</div>  
<svg class="skillSvg" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                                <path id="motionPath"  fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M16.5,215a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 397,0a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 -397,0">
                             </path>
                            </g>
                            <g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
                                <circle id="mainCircle" cx="371.408" cy="110.368" r="45" fill="#9CBEFF"/>
                            </g>
                            <circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" opacity="0" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="tomato" >                               
                            <!-- До начала анимации красный шарик скрыт-->                              
                              <animate
                                attributeName="opacity" begin="an1.begin"
                                dur="0.01s"
                                to="1"
                                fill="freeze" />                                 
                            <!-- Первая половина анимации от синего круга до начальной точки патча M16.5,215  -->
                            
                        <animateMotion
                               id="an1"
                               dur="2s"
                               begin="indefinite"
                               repeatCount="1"
                               keyPoints="0.6;1"
                               keyTimes="0;1"
                               calcMode="linear"
                               fill="freeze"
                                >
                             <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                        </animateMotion> 
                           <!-- Вторая половина анимации от начальной точки патча M16.5,215 до синего круга Начинается после окончания первой анимации -->
                            
                             <animateMotion
                              id="an2"
                              dur="5s"
                              begin="an1.end"
                              fill="freeze"
                              keyPoints="0;0.6"
                              keyTimes="0;1"
                              >
                                <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                            </animateMotion> 
                                            
                            </circle>

                            <!-- Style path -->                                
                            <defs>
                                <filter id="filter0_d" x="11" y="15" width="418" height="418" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>

                                <filter id="filter1_d" x="322.408" y="65.3682" width="98" height="98" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>
                            </defs>
                            <!-- ********** -->
                        </svg>
```

**UPDATE**

Можно попробовать вариант вместо вращения красного шарика, вращать группу, в которой будет и путь и красный шарик. Выглядеть будет точно также, если бы вращался только один шарик вдоль пути. И в этом варианте можно использовать вашу версию патча для траектории движения шарика.

Для этого создаем группу и вращаем её

```
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
   <path id="motionPath" transform="rotate(135 215 215)" fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M16.5,215a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 397,0a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 -397,0"/>
<circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" cx="378" cy="105" r="15" fill="tomato" /> 
  <!-- Анимация вращения группы -->
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="mainCircle.click" dur="4s" values="0 215 215;-360 215 215" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</g>
```

```html
<svg class="skillSvg" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                                <path id="motionPath" transform="rotate(135 215 215)" fill="none" stroke="#6699FC" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10"  d="M16.5,215a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 397,0a198.5,198.5 0 1,0 -397,0">
                                
                                </path>
                                <circle class="circleSvg" id="circle" cx="378" cy="105" r="15" fill="tomato" /> 
                                    <!-- Анимация вращения группы -->
                                   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="mainCircle.click" dur="4s" values="0 215 215;-360 215 215" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
                            </g>
                            <g filter="url(#filter1_d)">
                                <circle id="mainCircle" cx="371.408" cy="110.368" r="45" fill="#9CBEFF"/>
                            </g>
                                                           
                         <!-- Style path -->                                
                            <defs>
                                <filter id="filter0_d" x="11" y="15" width="408" height="408" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>

                                <filter id="filter1_d" x="322.408" y="65.3682" width="98" height="98" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                                    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                    <feOffset dy="4"/>
                                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
                                    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                                    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                                </filter>
                            </defs>
                            <!-- ********** -->
                        </svg>
```

Comment: Используя последний пример красный шарик заканчивает в M16.5,215, какой keyPoints прописать, чтобы он заканчивал под синим шариком?

Comment: @EugeneDark я попробовал много вариантов keyPoints прописать. Тот который есть в первом ответе идеально работает в Firefox, но не работает в Chrome  Поэтому я сделал второй ответ с новым path, который работает одинаково везде