# Как управлять анимацией движения с помощью Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Этот вопрос инициирован ответом в топике [Как заставить circle двигаться по path с определенного места?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161740/28748)

Как выяснилось Chrome обрабатывает с ошибками атрибуты анимации SVG `keyPoints` и `keyTimes`.
Поэтому невозможно изменить стартовую точку и направление движения без применения JS.

У меня есть SVG анимация кругового движения шарика по заданной трассе движения.

```css
.container {
width:35vw;
height:35vh;
}
.path {
fill:none;
stroke:#679AFF;
stroke-width:3;

}
#BigCircle { 
fill:#679AFF;
opacity:0.9;

}
#redBall {
fill:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid;">
  <g>
  <path class="path" d="m381.4 107.3c-4.7-7.2-9.9-14-15.5-20.6-5.5-6.5-11.1-12.9-17.4-18.7-7.4-6.8-15.4-13.1-23.8-18.7-7.6-5-15.7-9-23.8-12.9-8.8-4.3-17.7-8.5-27.1-11.6-8.8-2.9-17.9-5-27.1-6.4-10-1.6-20.1-2.7-30.3-2.6-10.8 0.1-21.6 1.4-32.2 3.2-11.8 2-23.5 4.6-34.8 8.4-9.1 3.1-17.9 7.1-26.4 11.6-9.2 4.9-18 10.5-26.4 16.7-6.6 4.9-12.7 10.5-18.7 16.1-5.8 5.5-11.6 11.2-16.7 17.4-4.9 5.9-9.4 12.2-13.5 18.7-4.7 7.3-9.2 14.7-12.9 22.5-3.6 7.5-6.5 15.3-9 23.2-3.3 10.5-6.1 21.3-7.7 32.2C16.6 195.5 16.4 205.3 16.5 215c0.1 9 0.9 18 2.2 26.9 1.5 10.4 3.6 20.8 6.4 30.9 2.4 8.6 5.3 17 9 25.1 3.6 7.9 8.2 15.3 12.9 22.5 4.4 6.7 9.2 13.1 14.2 19.3 4.9 6 10.1 11.8 15.5 17.4 5 5.1 9.8 10.5 15.5 14.8 6.2 4.6 13.3 7.7 20 11.6 8.4 4.9 16.2 10.9 25.1 14.8 7.2 3.2 15 4.9 22.5 7.1 8.5 2.4 17 5.1 25.8 6.4 9.1 1.5 18.4 1.9 27.7 1.9 9.9 0 19.8-0.5 29.6-1.9 8.9-1.3 17.8-3.3 26.4-5.8 9.5-2.8 18.7-6.2 27.7-10.3 8.2-3.7 16.3-8 23.8-12.9 8-5.2 15.3-11.2 22.5-17.4 7.6-6.5 15.4-13 21.9-20.6 7.1-8.3 12.9-17.7 18.7-27.1 5.4-8.8 10.7-17.6 14.8-27.1 4.1-9.5 7.3-19.5 9.7-29.6 2.7-11.2 4.5-22.6 5.2-34.1 0.6-10.9-0.2-21.9-1.3-32.9-1.1-10.8-2.3-21.7-5.2-32.2-2.8-10.2-7-20.1-11.6-29.6-4.1-8.7-8.9-17.1-14.2-25.1z" />
  <circle id="redBall" cx="378" cy="105" r="15"  > 
    
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="start.click" dur="4s" values="0 215 215; 359 215 215" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" />  
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="reverse.click" dur="4s" values="359 215 215; 0 215 215" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </circle> 
</g>  
   <circle id="BigCircle" cx="378" cy="105" r="45"  />  
     <circle id="start" cx="50" cy="410" r="12" fill="#679AFF"  />  
       <text x="20" y="385" font-size="18" fill="#679AFF"> Вперед </text>
       <circle id="reverse" cx="380" cy="410" r="12" fill="tomato"  /> 
         <text x="360" y="385" font-size="18" fill="tomato"> Назад </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Для решения в этом вопросе я не использовал `keyPoints` и `keyTimes` в `animateMotion`, но выбрал анимацию трансформации вращения. `<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate"`

Но при изменении направления вращения при клике на зелёные и красные кнопки анимация начинается со стартовой точки. Другими словами, если запущена анимация вращения по часовой стрелке, то при переключении другой кнопкой направления вращения, результат предыдущей анимации сбрасывается. Всё начинается из стартовой точки.

**Вопрос:**

Как добиться остановки и запуска анимации с того же места, а также реверса движения и отмены результатов предыдущих анимаций движения?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Собственно всё тоже самое только вручную и адаптивно.

```js
(function() {
  let w,h, hw,hh,
  circle_radius, frame_id,
  angle = 0, reverse_v = 1

  resize(); onresize = resize
    
  play_button.onclick    = play
  pause_button.onclick   = pause
  cancel_button.onclick  = cancel
  reverse_button.onclick = reverse

  function play() {
    !frame_id && animate()
  }

  function pause() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame_id)
    frame_id = null
  }

  function reverse() {
    reverse_v *= -1
  }

  function cancel() {
    pause()
    reverse_v = 1
    angle = 0
    placeSpinner(angle)
  }

  function placeSpinner(angle) {
    const cos = Math.cos(angle)
    const sin = Math.sin(angle)
    const spinner_x = hw + cos * circle_radius
    const spinner_y = hh + sin * circle_radius

    spinner.setAttribute('cx', spinner_x)
    spinner.setAttribute('cy', spinner_y)
  }
  
  function animate() {
    angle += 0.01 * reverse_v
    placeSpinner(angle)
    frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }

  function resize() {
    w = innerWidth; h = innerHeight * 0.8
    hw = w/2; hh = h/2
    circle_radius = Math.min(w,h) * 0.4

    const spinner_radius = circle_radius * 0.1
    spinner.setAttribute('r', spinner_radius)

    svg.setAttribute('width', w)
    svg.setAttribute('height', h)

    circle.setAttribute('cx', hw)
    circle.setAttribute('cy', hh)
    circle.setAttribute('r', circle_radius)

    placeSpinner(angle)
  }
})()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + 5px);
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 80vh 20vh;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #679AFF;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

#spinner {
  fill: tomato;
}

button {
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: #679AFF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: calc(2px + 0.1vw + 0.1vh);
  padding: 3vh 3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <svg id="svg" >
     <circle id="circle" /> 
     <circle id="spinner" /> 
  </svg>
  <div class="controll">
    <button id="pause_button">Pause</button>
    <button id="play_button">Play</button>
    <button id="reverse_button">Reverse</button>
    <button id="cancel_button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ᅠh  Хороший ответ, интересное для меня решение

Answer (score 6):

Данная задача решается с помощью [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API)

1. Запуск анимации - [Animation.play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/play)
2. Реверс направления движения анимации решается с помощью метода [Animation.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/reverse)
3. Пауза - [animation.pause();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/pause)
4. Сброс результатов предыдущих анимаций - [Animation.cancel()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/cancel)

Остаётся добавить кнопки, повесить на них слушателей с обработчиками клика

```js
let spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
let spinnerAnimation = spinner.animate([
    {
        transform: 'rotate(0)'
    },
    {
        transform: 'rotate(359deg)'
    }
], {
    duration: 3000,
    iterations: Infinity
});

document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  spinnerAnimation.pause();
});
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  spinnerAnimation.play(); 
});
document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  spinnerAnimation.reverse(); 
});
document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  spinnerAnimation.cancel(); 
});
```

```css
.controll {
margin-left:4rem;
}
.container {
width:430px;
height:430px;
}
.path {
fill:none;
stroke:#679AFF;
stroke-width:3;

}
#BigCircle { 
fill:#679AFF;
opacity:0.9;

}
#spinner {
transform-origin: 215px 215px;
fill:tomato;
}
button {
  background-color: #679AFF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" width="430" height="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="path" d="m381.4 107.3c-4.7-7.2-9.9-14-15.5-20.6-5.5-6.5-11.1-12.9-17.4-18.7-7.4-6.8-15.4-13.1-23.8-18.7-7.6-5-15.7-9-23.8-12.9-8.8-4.3-17.7-8.5-27.1-11.6-8.8-2.9-17.9-5-27.1-6.4-10-1.6-20.1-2.7-30.3-2.6-10.8 0.1-21.6 1.4-32.2 3.2-11.8 2-23.5 4.6-34.8 8.4-9.1 3.1-17.9 7.1-26.4 11.6-9.2 4.9-18 10.5-26.4 16.7-6.6 4.9-12.7 10.5-18.7 16.1-5.8 5.5-11.6 11.2-16.7 17.4-4.9 5.9-9.4 12.2-13.5 18.7-4.7 7.3-9.2 14.7-12.9 22.5-3.6 7.5-6.5 15.3-9 23.2-3.3 10.5-6.1 21.3-7.7 32.2C16.6 195.5 16.4 205.3 16.5 215c0.1 9 0.9 18 2.2 26.9 1.5 10.4 3.6 20.8 6.4 30.9 2.4 8.6 5.3 17 9 25.1 3.6 7.9 8.2 15.3 12.9 22.5 4.4 6.7 9.2 13.1 14.2 19.3 4.9 6 10.1 11.8 15.5 17.4 5 5.1 9.8 10.5 15.5 14.8 6.2 4.6 13.3 7.7 20 11.6 8.4 4.9 16.2 10.9 25.1 14.8 7.2 3.2 15 4.9 22.5 7.1 8.5 2.4 17 5.1 25.8 6.4 9.1 1.5 18.4 1.9 27.7 1.9 9.9 0 19.8-0.5 29.6-1.9 8.9-1.3 17.8-3.3 26.4-5.8 9.5-2.8 18.7-6.2 27.7-10.3 8.2-3.7 16.3-8 23.8-12.9 8-5.2 15.3-11.2 22.5-17.4 7.6-6.5 15.4-13 21.9-20.6 7.1-8.3 12.9-17.7 18.7-27.1 5.4-8.8 10.7-17.6 14.8-27.1 4.1-9.5 7.3-19.5 9.7-29.6 2.7-11.2 4.5-22.6 5.2-34.1 0.6-10.9-0.2-21.9-1.3-32.9-1.1-10.8-2.3-21.7-5.2-32.2-2.8-10.2-7-20.1-11.6-29.6-4.1-8.7-8.9-17.1-14.2-25.1z" />
  <circle id="spinner" cx="378" cy="105" r="15"  /> 
   <circle id="BigCircle" cx="378" cy="105" r="45"  />
</svg>
</div>
<div class="controll">
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="reverse">Reverse</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: когда нажимаю reverse маленький круг возвращается назад как сделать чтобы он двигался вперед ?

Comment: @Leks повторно нажми на reverse